# error while restoring dump.rdb

Tags: redis

i had a backup from dump.rdb database in my last server and i just copied it with `scp` command to new server and i restore it like this :

`service redis-server stop 
cp -r /root/dump.rdb/ /var/lib/redis/
cd /var/lib/redis && chown redis:redis dump.rdb
service redis-server start`

but after using the last command i got this error :

**Job for redis-server.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status redis-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.**

as i know it maybe from redis version but i dont know what version is my Dump.rdb is for .

do you have any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at least i found this out that my redis version was lower than Database's Saved redis version .

you can load the lower redis databases on high versions but you can't lost higher versions in lower versions . 
and when i use `sudo apt-get install redis-server` it just installs the lower versions of redis which is commited in ubuntu community . 
so i installed the new one with the commands :

`wget redis-4.0.8.tar.gz
tar -xzf redis-4.0.8.tar.gz
cd redis-4.0.8
make
make install
make test` 
then i have to edit redis.conf like this : 
`nano redis.conf`

i set the database name like this :

`dbfilename dump.rdb`

and at least i set the database directory  :

`dir /var/lib/redis/`
then press CTRL + X  then Y then ENTER . 
then use these commands :

`cd src
redis-server`

now just close the terminal without anything . 
now reconnect and test :

`redis-cli get PING`
it have to treat like this :

`127.0.0.1:6379> "PONG"`